# jQuery detect maximize and restore buttons from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen a few posts but none really answered my question.
I want to detect the browsers built in `maximize` and `restore` button clicks on the top right of the browser next to the `[X]` close button.  I would like to trigger a function from this.

`Window Resize` only works when you grab a corner and manually resize the browser.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {});
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
  $('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3vKz/1/)**

Works fine in FF and Safari on the maximize/restore button.

Comment: thank you,  the function i was calling needs a callback!

Comment: Worked also on Opera v29 and Chrome v42. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on OSX when minimizing to the dock and restoring, but does work on maximize (zoom is what they call it on OSX).